# Unable to Launch Xamarin Android Player

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-android-player

I am getting the following error when I try to launch Xamarin Android Player.
I have tried reducing the allocated memory in Virtual Box, as suggested in some other forums but no results.

I am using Virtual Box `V5.0.4`.

Kindly guide on resolving the issue.

The Android is working in Virtual Box when I change

> Settings>Network>Adapter1>Attached to

to `NAT` by going into the in virtual box but as I launch the Xamarin Android Player or GenyMotion. it resets it to `Host-Only Adapter` and the emulator stops working.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You might want to look at the log file and see what the actual problem is: log file location https://blogs.oracle.com/fatbloke/entry/virtualbox_log_files

Answer (score 0):

I would update virtual box to 5.0.20 from [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) try it again.

If that doesn't work then try reinstalling Xamarin Android Player.

If that doesn't work then I would recommend trying [GenyMotion](https://www.genymotion.com/features/)

Check this [forum post too](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/27167/xamarin-android-player-error)

They say this:

> I solved this issue by reducing the RAM Value in Virtual Box.
>
> 1. Go to Virtual Box
> 2. Select Your Device
> 3. Go to settings -> System -> Motherboard.
> 4. Reduce Base Memory.

Or this might help:

> Try starting the emulator in VirtualBox. It will give you a specific error, which you can then google for more info.
>
> In my case, the issue was VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND, and the solution was here

solution https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/14604#comment:1

Comment: Yes, I have tried GenyMotion, it is also giving the same kind of error,
Actually the Android directly works in VB when I change network adapter setting to `NAT` in place of `Host-Only` but Xamarin Android Player and GenyMotion both needs `Host-Only` setting to work.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have Virtualization Enabled in your BIOS settings.

Another workaround:

> 1. Uninstall previous versions of XAP.
> 2. Open up VirtualBox and remove all of the XAP devices, choose to delete files.
> 3. Open the VirtualBox Virtual Media Manager and ensure there are no data.vdi, system.vdi or sdcard.vdi files remaining. If there are,
>      release and remove them.
> 4. Delete C:\ProgramData\AndroidPlayer

Source: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=24817

Comment: Virtualization is enabled in BIOS.

Comment: Ok, give the 2nd workaround a try. Can you also share the log, by the way?

Comment: Android is working in Virtual Box when I change `Settings>Network>Adapter1>Attached to` to 'NAT' by going into the in virtual box but as I launch the Xamarin Android Player or GenyMotion. it resets it to 'Host-Only Adapter' and the emulator stops working.